# AWS Athena is changed and is now failing with large queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

AWS Athena has been a reliable workhorse for large-scale queries, we run some of our daily ETL using Athena.

AWS [recently introduced a way to reserve Athena capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/introducing-athena-provisioned-capacity/), and now all of our larger queries are failing with:

> Query exhausted resources at this scale factor.

These queries are not complex at all. but involve a lot of data. They read 2-3GB of data.

If you then go ahead and reserve capacity, the cost becomes quite high. A reserved capacity of 24 dpu costs around $70 for an 8 hour session, which is the minimum.

I then get an error message like this

> **EXCEEDED_RESERVED_CAPACITY_LIMIT_EXCEPTION**: Insufficient capacity to
> execute this query. This query requires 124 DPU, which exceeds the
> total number of DPU in reservation etl. Add capacity and try again
> later.

Has anyone else started experiencing this issue? how did you resolve?

EDIT : i have found a pattern to the queries that are now failing with Query exhausted resources at this scale factor. These are generally queries in the form:

```
with d as (
 select x,y from z where a='something'
 union all 
 select x,y from z where a='something'
 union all 
 select x,y from z where a='something'
 union all 
 select x,y from z where a='something'
 )
 select *
  from d
  join something as e on e.xxx=d.xxx
```

Comment: It seems you will need to have atleast 124 DPU in case of this query, but yeah this is going to be expensive.

Comment: but then what about the next query that requires 125 or 300 or ??? i have to provision at the max i need (which is hard to find out in advance)

Comment: Also, note that previously the cost of these queries was 20,000x cheaper. Running the single 3GB query on Athena used to cost 3/1000*$5 = $0.015, now it would cost $300

Comment: Why not just use `select x, y from z where a in ('something1', 'something2', 'something3')`?

Comment: How many files are using in your query? What is the format of the files (eg CSV or Snappy-compressed Parquet)? It might be that you can optimise the file format and make queries easier.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein its pivoting a wide table to be long and thin, parquet, fairly well optimised files, (a thousand or so), it only runs for 3 mins normally and has not failed before like this, now all similar queries fail. must be related to an aws change. the data isn't even the same between the different queries just the pattern.

Comment: additional info/workaround hack - these queries run fine with Athena V2, but fail every time with V3, so i set up a separate workgroup to run them with V2 . Note that these had been working fine with V3 previously (i had not just swapped over) @JohnRotenstein fyi.

Comment: Feel free to provide this information back to Amazon by using the "Feedback" button in the Athena console. I don't know who/when it is read, but it's the best you can do without subscribing to AWS Support.

Comment: Thanks John, will do. We were already slowly migrating to dbt+databricks so this will hasten the migration.